# 3X4 contingency table, which test?

Tags: chi-squared-test, contingency-tables

I am testing to see if participants' responses to the same cue word given in written format and oral format differ from each other. To do this I set up a control condition where participants give responses to the same cues when mode of presentation is the same for both time1 and time2 (e.g. written-written), and an experimental condition where they respond to the same cues but the mode of presentation is different for time1 and time2 (e.g. written-oral). Their responses are classified under one of four classification categories and it's these I'd like to compare. So my contingency table looks like this:

[image: image of contingency table]

Which statistical test should I use to see if there are difference between the control and experimental conditions in time2 in comparison to time1? I am told a Chi-squared test for homogeneity is proper? But I'm not sure. Is it better if I just run two chi-squared test on each condition separately? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Unclear. How many subjects? 120? 240? Please give detail about tasks performed by each subject, and how the table was made.